# Keyup function is calling twice

Tags: jquery, keyup

why keyup function in jquery triggering twice ? 
I have tried with unbind and off method..but its not working
Anyone help me pls

```
$("#inputid").keyup(function(e) {
             console.log("inputttt calling twice");
              var userQuantity =$('#id').val();

          });
```

Comment: Sure ..Thanks i will edit in question

Comment: you need to edit the original question and not add the code into the comments. The edit button is just below the tags

Comment: My guess is you are adding the same event listener twice. Are you loading the same script twice?

Comment: this only console.log once - https://fiddle.jshell.net/dhoze440/1/

Comment: @Jim I ll check again my script is loading twice..

Answer (score -1):

Unless you are adding the listener twice it would not behave like that usually.

To prevent multiple event listeners on the same element, try removing the listener before adding one. Another way is to define the callback function before adding the event listener, that way, no matter how many times you do `addEventListener` it will only add the listener once to the element. Something like below.

**Providing the callback function beforehand**

```js
var input = document.getElementById('some');


var callback = function(event) {
  console.log("PRINT");
}

input.addEventListener("keyup", callback)

// input.removeEventListener("keyup", callback)

input.addEventListener("keyup", callback)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="some" value="" >
```

**Anonymous function as callback**

```js
var input = document.getElementById('some');

input.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
  console.log("PRINT");
})

// input.removeEventListener("keyup", callback)

input.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
  console.log("PRINT");
})
```

```html
<input id="some" value="">
```

Comment: how does this help when OP is using jQuery to add the listener?

Comment: @charlietfl Well, I thought, from the title of the question, people who google similar will find the answer helpful. It's upto the OP whether to accept this as answer or not. Your comment already helped her.